# (Dis)Advantages of basing a proof assistant on CH correspondence?

Tags: coq, lean, isabelle, proof-assistant

Major proof assistants like Lean and Coq are fundamentally based on the Curry-Howard correspondence: propositions are encoded as types, quantified propositions are encoded as dependent types, proofs are instances of those types, and so on.

On the other hand, I read that Isabelle (another major proof assistant) is not based on the CH correspondence.

My question is: what are the advantages (and disadvantages) of basing a proof assistant on this correspondence?

Comment: https://langdev.stackexchange.com is riddled with "pro and con" questions, and when someone fails to list some cons in their anwer, they get told off and downvoted. I do hope we're not adopting their customs.

Comment: BTW, I don't know how tags are managed on SE, but I'm surprised I couldn't find any "Curry-Howard" related tag here.

Comment: Strange, I added the tag, let's see what the moderators will do.

Answer (score 3):

Let us separate two things here: having *dependent types*, and using them to express logic a la *propositions-as-types*.

As far as formalization of mathematics is concerned, **there are no disadvantages to having dependent types**. Mathematics is naturally expressed using dependence and any attempt to remove it results in awkwardness that is then remedied in one way or another.

Regarding the second point, **neither Lean nor Coq use propositions-as-types**. They both have a notion of impredicative propositions, through which logic is expressed in a standard form.

However, there is something to be said about *pure* propositions-as-types and *pure* logic. They are both inadequate for formalization:

- In pure propositions-as-types a la Martin-Löf type theory we cannot express *abstract existence*, i.e., that something exists without having access to a specific witness, as we must always use $\Sigma$, which automatically exposes the existential witness. Thus for example there is no reasonable definition of surjection in Martin-Löf type theory. One has to do acrobatics known as "setoids".
- In pure logic we cannot express *explicit existence*, i.e., that we have actually constructed a specific thing, as we must always use $\exists$, which automatically hides the existential witness. One consequence of this is that mathematicians are unable to speak precisely. They write "there exists $X$ such that ..." instead of "we construct $X$ such that ..." because someone told them in logic class that $\exists$ is the only formal notion of existence.

Mathematics needs *both* kinds of existence. Lean has it, Coq has it, Homotopy type theory has it. Agda does not (without postulates) and HOL does not either because it is a logic (although it compenstates by having an expressive term language and meta-theoretic devices, such as definitions).

Comment: I think some talk about the Curry Howard isomorphism in a looser sense (for pedagogical purposes) as explaining why Lean (or Coq) uses the same language for term proofs and definitions.   Of course those proofs take place in Prop so it isn’t full CH isomorphism.  (I think you could find it used this way in TPIL which is maybe where the OP is getting this idea.)

Comment: Well, it is not a good idea to dilute the Curry Howard correspondence by making it more non-specific and historically inaccurate. For pedagogical purposes, perhaps it would be better to remind the students (and apparently their teachers) that Russell's and Church's type theories had types of logical truth values, and so one was free to mix "logic" and "other types". The Curry-Howard correspondence came a lot later, and was and is traditionally tied to the idea that "all types" can serve as propositions.

Comment: “there are no disadvantages to having dependent types”.  I think to be fair to the Isabelle/HOL folks, they would say DTT has some disadvantages like a larger kernel, a more complicated logic that is further from standard set theory foundations, etc.

Comment: The Isabelle/HOL folks are more than welcome to explain their point of view in a separate answer. See my comment below the question. Also, I specifically qualified my statement with "as far as formalization of mathematics is concerned" (so not "as far as meta-theory is concerned" or "as far as implementation is concerned").

Comment: Being further from standard set theory foundation is an advantage in many respects.

Comment: Regarding "CH in a looser sense", that is related to another question I asked yesterday https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162105/curry-howard-isomorphism-and-non-constructive-logic

I don't know much about type theory, I actually got into proof assistants by trying the natural number game in Lean and it is says (see https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/xena/natural_number_game/?world=6&level=1):
"In Lean, Propositions, like sets, are types, and proofs, like elements of sets, are terms."

Comment: @AndrejBauer What I understand from your answer is that Lean does not implement a strict propositions-as-types correspondence as formalized in CH, as such a strict correspondence would be too restrictive regarding the statements which can be expressed.

Still, can we say that Lean design was motivated by the CH correspondence in some regards? (and maybe, my initial question should be interpreted in that loose sense?)

Comment: I do not know enough history to be able to tell whether the Calculus of Inductive Constructions, on which Coq and Lean are based, was inspired directly by the Curry-Howard correspondence. It could be the case that the authors of CiC looks at Church's simple type theory and said "hey, let's make it dependent and intuitionistic". You'd have to ask them.

Comment: What seems to be clear is that Lean relied heavily on the ideas developed by the designers of older proof assistants (most obviously Coq), and to some degree also functional programming languages. In this sense Lean is not as much a fundamental innovation as it is an engineering accomplishment par excellence. (Thankfully, since us academic types obsess with inventing revolutionary inventions all the time.)

Comment: [This blog post](https://lawrencecpaulson.github.io/2023/08/23/Propositions_as_Types.html) talks about  Curry-Howard isomorphism and the (non-)use of it in proof assistants. The [Simple Type Theory is not too Simple](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.09366.pdf) paper has some discussion about potential disadvantages of dependent types in formalization of mathematics, see "The song of the Sirens" section.

Comment: @SlawomirK.: Isabelle's locales are the Isabelle's remedy for lack of dependent types. They *are* dependent types bolted on top of HOL. But don't get me wrong, I have the highest admiration for Isabelle/HOL. The amount of math foudn in there is staggering. I am only trying to observe that dependency creeps in one way or another everywhere, and for good reasons: mathematicians use it all the time.

Comment: BTW, the [Zariski locale in agda-unimath](https://unimath.github.io/agda-unimath/commutative-algebra.zariski-locale.html) formalization has none of the problems that Kevin Buzzard lamented about. (I am told there won't be any problems with the structure sheaf either, but let's wait and see.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer I imagine, the difference in the mathematical statement is something like, “there exists an $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2 = 4$” vs. “if $x$ is constructed as $x:=2$, then $x^2=4$.” Am I misunderstanding? If I am, could you give a specific example of how the two existence notions are expressed differently in Lean or Coq?

Comment: I talked about it in 2019, see [this blog post](https://math.andrej.com/2019/07/04/what-is-an-explicit-bijection-fpsac-2019-slides/), with slides and video.